# variable is not None works but not variable doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, function, nonetype

I was trying to solve a dynamic programming problem in Pyhon 3.x. I wanted to create a memo dictionary object. After assigning default value of `None` to memo parameter, the check for `None` with `not object` doesn't seem to work, but if I change it to `object is None`, it works fine.
By doesn't work, I mean this condition doesn't evaluate to `True` in case of `not object`, and the following indented code isn't executed.
This results in TLE on LeetCode. But using `is None` check does work, and it assigns a dictionary to memo, and thus caching works as intended, and the solution passes.

Why does this happen?

```
        def lcs(i, j, memo = None):
            if not memo:
                memo = {}
```

vs

```
        def lcs(i, j, memo = None):
            if memo is None:
                memo = {}
```

I called the function with `return lcs(0, 0)`.

Edit: On my system Python IDLE, both expressions evaluate to True. So I think, the LeetCode platform handles the code differently.

[image: Code on my system.]

Edit 2: sometime after @buran pointed out, these partial snippets were producing the expected result on LeetCode too, I also tried the partial snippets, and indeed they were giving the expected result. But then when I tried the whole code(used from past submission), surprisingly it also gave the expected result (new memo was actually created). I wasn't able to actually reproduce the problem I faced earlier until today.
for a different problem, the code is again showing the same behavior, Now I think I am missing something here. That's why I'm posting the whole code this time. Can someone spot and explain why both these codes give different result.

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, s: str) -> int:
        
        def lps(l, r, memo = None):
            if memo is None:
                memo = {}
            if (l, r) not in memo:
                if l > r:
                    memo[(l, r)] = 0
                elif l == r:
                    memo[(l, r)] = 1
                elif s[l] == s[r]:
                    memo[(l, r)] = lps(l+1, r-1, memo) + 2
                else:
                    memo[(l, r)] = max(lps(l+1, r, memo), lps(l, r-1, memo))
            return memo[(l, r)]
        
        return lps(0, len(s)-1)
```

vs

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, s: str) -> int:
        
        def lps(l, r, memo = None):
            if not memo:
                memo = {}
            if (l, r) not in memo:
                if l > r:
                    memo[(l, r)] = 0
                elif l == r:
                    memo[(l, r)] = 1
                elif s[l] == s[r]:
                    memo[(l, r)] = lps(l+1, r-1, memo) + 2
                else:
                    memo[(l, r)] = max(lps(l+1, r, memo), lps(l, r-1, memo))
            return memo[(l, r)]
        
        return lps(0, len(s)-1)
```

Can someone please also tell if and what should I remove from my past edits or the original post. This is becoming a really long post. (I'm new here)

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work"? Is an error thrown? Is the result not what you expected? If possible, please provide code that someone can copy and paste that illustrates the problem.

Comment: It's not what you're asking, but how about `def lcs(i, j, memo = {}):`

Comment: @danh - default values can be tricky. In your example, there is a single default dict object that is always used when the parameter is missing. Each call keeps getting that same dict which will hold whatever data happens to be in it from the other calls.

Comment: I see. Thanks @tdelaney.  BTW, OP, on my python interpreter, `memo = None`, followed by `not memo` interprets to `True`, so does `not None`, so does `memo is None`

Comment: @myrtlecat I've added the details to the question. Please check.

Comment: @danh using mutable default argument is considered a bad practice, and can lead to tricky bugs. See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments , https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html .

Comment: Please, post [mre]. At the moment with both snippets `memo` will be empty dict when you call `lcs(0, 0)`. Given that `lcs()` does not return anything (thus returning None) and that you call it as part of return statement  `return lcs()` probably there is something else going on - scope issue or a problem with if/else block or something

Comment: There will be difference between the two only when you pass argument for memo that is another value evaluated as False when Truth value tested, e.g 0, empty list

Comment: After you latest edit I tried the snippets again on LeetCode. They produce the same result as expected, no difference, when call `lcs(0, 0)`. Again, there is something else you do to get different result.

Comment: @buran Indeed, the snippets do give the expected result. Thanks. But I was able to reproduce these results today with different algorithm. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

`not` is a keyword which is equivalent to `!=`. So it has totally different meaning.

You can use `not` keyword as below (for example)

```
def lcs(i, j, memo = None):
            if memo is not None:
                memo = {}
```

The above code is equivalent to

```
def lcs(i, j, memo = None):
            if memo != None:
                memo = {}
```

If you want to use `not` keyword that badly, then use this code.

```
def lcs(i, j, memo = None):
            if not memo == None:
                memo = {}
```

If you find have any doubts, let me know.

Comment: Your first example `if memo is not None: memo = {}` is backwards. It only assigns the dict if the user passed one in. `not` is different than `!=` (they are implemented by different magic methods and do not have to resolve to the same truth value). `None` is one of the few guaranteed singletons in python. `memo is None` and `memo is not None` are the preferred ways to test.

Answer (score 1):

From [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

*By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero*.

An empty `dict` has length zero, so is `False`. If you call `lcs` with a memo dictionary, but that dictionary doesn't happen to have anything in it, it will test `False` and `if not memo: memo = {}` will create a new memo object for you. That code can't tell the difference between an empty memo and None.

The `if memo is None` is the proper way to assign a memo only if the caller hasn't passed one in.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've used Python so bear with me but I think I can explain the general programming concept.

In the first one you are checking if memo doesn't exist.

```
if not memo
```

Meaning to continue if memo does not exist.

In the second one you are checking that memo does exist and that it is set to None.

```
if memo is None
```

To continue if memo exists (a pre-condition to going into the check) and it is set to None